# Passing the parent class pointer to child

Tags: qt, class, methods, properties, parent-child

I have two classes declared as below but I get compile errors and it seems to be due to the loop #include. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My purpose is tp let the child class keep the pointer to the parent so that the child can access the parent's methods and properties.

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H
#include "child.h"

class Parent
{
public:
    Child* mychild;
    Parent();
};

#endif // PARENT_H


#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H
#include "parent.h"
class Child
{
public:
    Parent* myparent;
    Child();
};

#endif // CHILD_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only store a pointer to the class, you do not need to have the full class definition available in the header, you can use a forward class declaration, like this:

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

class Child;

class Parent
{
public:
    Child* mychild;
    Parent();
};

#endif // PARENT_H


#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H

class Parent;

class Child
{
public:
    Parent* myparent;
    Child();
};

#endif // CHILD_H
```

You then have to include parent.h in child.cpp, and child.h in parent.cpp.